Websocket connection error with Nginx on Linux server
So, the app in question is not using signalr to perform tasks, but default websocket connection for blazor is showing the error. My nginx setup
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {
    "~*Upgrade" $http_connection;
    default keep-alive;
}

# Main domain
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name fanatic360.xyz;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bspeaks_app:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_read_timeout 100s; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    } 
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name fanatic360.xyz;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fanatic360.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fanatic360.xyz/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_timeout       1d;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers               ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets       off;
    ssl_stapling              off;

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bspeaks_app:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

     
}
}

two things happen with this setup. One is a warning during nginx build that says:

[warn] 35#35: could not build optimal proxy_headers_hash, you should increase either proxy_headers_hash_max_size: 1024 or proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size
nginx: [warn] could not build optimal proxy_headers_hash, you should increase either proxy_headers_hash_max_size: 1024 or proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size

the other is this error from console when running the app
the app is running, but there are problems. I have deployed this app on a windows server without any problem obviously. But my first try to deploy it on a linux server I am getting this. Unfortunately my company is not going to invest in windows servers, and move forward with linux ones. So I badly need to figure this out.

@DavidC.Rankin Should I close it here and ask there?

Ok, I forgot to mention this is all running via a docker container on a linux server.

Then you are good here. [docker] anything seems fine as a topic. I've retracted the close vote.

@DavidC.Rankin Ok
